# Showing data in one activity depends on choice in others activity listView - how to

Tags: java, android, listview

I am developing an android news app which has goal to show titles in one activity in listView, and by clicking on each title it must open another activity and show description, photo and also title. These are pulled from web in JSON.
For now, I have list view in first activity which has been populated with titles from JSON,using AsyncTask and SimpleAdapter, and now, I need some theory boost how to make further progress.
So, how can I select one title and by this title get other parts of JSON and show them in another activity? 
Any advice?

Comment: You can pass the title to the next Activity as an `Extra` in an `Intent`. You can then use your web API to get the JSON based on that title. You should be able to find a number of resources if you Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an `onClickListener` on the items in `listView`. In the `onClickListener` get the title and start a new activity. For the new activity add the data you need to send.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
// add the data here
intent.putExtra("title", title);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `DetailActivity.java`

```
String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
```

make an API call with the above `title`